# run command only at the first occurrence of the window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I would like to know if the following situation it's possible. Let's say I have the next `$.resize()` function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 500) console.log('Small');
});
```

I know that the above will log `Small` as long as the size of the window is under 500. So this means if you resize your window from 500 to 200, the `Small` will be logged about 300 times.

Well, that means if you actually have some heavy function running under those circumstances, the browser might crash because it will run over and over again until you stop resizing or the circumstances change.

So that is why I'm asking if there would be a way to run that hypothetical function only at the first occurrence of the condition ?

Comment: You can set a global variable after it's ran once.  If that variable's set, don't run the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event bind which runs the passed in function once only at the first occurrence of the event.

```
$(window).one("resize", function(){
    if($(window).width() < 500) console.log('Small');
});
```

Comment: hell no you were like 5 sec faster.

Comment: `one` is definitely what he wants.. +1

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely what I want :) That way I don't risk crashing browsers :) And it's much more elegant than using a `setTimeOut` function.

Comment: Although this theoretically works, the issue is that it only tracks exactly one resize event. Any future resizes are completely lost. If you're wanting the app to change dynamically as the screen size changes, this will only work for the first resize and none past that.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // apply whatever you want to do with it, other conditions etc... 
    // regardless of what you want to do, the following line unbinds the resize event 
    // from within the handler.. consider calling this once all your conditions are met
    $(window).unbind("resize");
});
```

this handler executes your code, then unbinds the `resize` event from `window`

**Edit**: removed conditions. The purpose of this code is just to show how to call `unbind`, apply the conditions that are best for your scenario

**Edit 2**: Addressing one of the comments, `unbind` the way I presented on the code above, will ultimately unbind all handlers for the `resize` event. A better approach would be declaring the event handler in a separate method like this:

```
var Window_Resize = function(e) {
   // code goes here
};

$(window).resize(Window_Resize);
```

and to unbind, use this

```
$(window).unbind(Window_Resize)
```

This way you only remove that specific handler. Other handlers would still be bound to this event.

Comment: seems like you'd only want to unbind if the condition is true, right? Otherwise the first resize would unbind, regardless of the condition.

Comment: Your `if` statement isn't really doing anything.

Comment: if that condition is true, it writes on the log, next lines would still execute

Comment: This will unbind _all_ event handlers bound to `window`'s `resize` event. Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Sure, but it will also unbind if the window goes from 500 to 800, never firing "small" (or executing the callback as the author intended.)

Comment: @benekastah thanks for your input, my last edit addresses your concern :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `one` event handler in jquery to do it.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

like this

```
$(window).one('resize', function(){alert('lol');});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions. If you want the handler to be run the *very first* time you resize the window, you can force it to run only once:

```
$(window).one('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 500) console.log('Small');
});
```

But then you have a problem: it literally only runs *once*. What happens if they resize it again to be large?

A solution is to introduce a "tolerance" zone, where you run your code only if the window has been resized within a certain period of time:

```
var RESIZE_TOLERANCE = 200; // milliseconds

var last_resize = 0;

$(window).resize(function () {
    var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (current_time - last_resize < RESIZE_TOLERANCE) {
        return; // stop
    }

    last_resize = current_time;

    if ($(window).width() < 500) console.log('Small');
});
```

This forces the resize handler to run at maximum five times per second. You can change the tolerance if you so desire.

However, think of this situation: we resize down from 999px to 998px, firing the resize handler. Then we resize from 998px to 200px before the 200ms is up. The issue is that we have missed the resize event.

A much better solution is to keep track of the current small state and only execute your heavy code *if the state changes*:

```
var RESIZE_TOLERANCE = 100; // milliseconds
var SMALL_TOLERANCE = 500; // pixels
var last_resize = 0;
var small = $(window).width() < SMALL_TOLERANCE;

$(window).resize(function () {
    var current_time = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (current_time - last_resize < RESIZE_TOLERANCE) {
        return; // stop
    }

    last_resize = current_time;

    var is_small = $(window).width() < SMALL_TOLERANCE;

    if (is_small !== small) {
        // run expensive code here
        small = is_small;
    }
});
```

Now the tolerance is 100ms, which means we won't be recalculating the window's width more than that. (You can remove that or change it if you want.) We only run the expensive code if the state of the screen has changed. I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you will have to be creative if your requirements are subtly different.

Answer (score 0):

The straightfoward answer is:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() < 500 && !ranfirst) {
    ranfirst = true;
    console.log('Small');
  }
});
```

This probably won't work the way you're thinking, though it does satisfy the phrasing of your question. You might find you need to set a timeout to poll the size of the window and unset `ranfirst` when the size remains the same for 10 seconds or so.